# how to check is an element added to an array or not

Tags: java

Here I got this

```
public boolean addPerson(Person p1) {
    people[index] = p1;
    return true;
}
```

This method should add a person to my people array and also return true if success and false if fail to add. I try to write like this:

```
return people[index] = p1;
```

But this line will not work. How can I achieve this method and make it as simple as possible?

Comment: Why would the original code return `false` if it "failed to add"?

Comment: Sorry, but this question does not make sense.  Where does the value of `index` get set?  What does the declaration of `people` look like?  What condition would mean that you could not add an element to the array?  With the code you show there cannot be any failure unless `index` was >= the size of the array.  Since you haven't shown how the array is created or how `index` is set, we can't tell what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, should be using a for loop to check is the index empty or not like this:

```
public boolean addPerson(People person)
    {
        int index = 0;
        boolean success = false;
        for (Person position : p1) 
        {

            if(position==null)
            {
                //empty
                people[index] = person;
                success = true;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: This is not even *close* to what the question was talking about, even if, as the one who wrote the question, it is the answer you were looking for.